# Creating a list of keys for calling

Tags: python, kivy, jsonstore

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
def ContactCallback(instance):
    Friends = JsonStore('friendslist/'+accountname+'/offline.json')
    Friends.put(
        str(FriendsDatabase.get('Counter')['Count']),
        Nickname=NicknameIn.text,
        TimeZone=TzIn.text,
        Discord=DiscordIn.text,
        Hypixel=HypixelIn.text,
        Badlion=BadlionIn.text,
        Other1=Other3In.text,
        Other2=Other2In.text
    )
    FriendsDatabase.put(
        'Counter',
        Count=1 + ((FriendsDatabase.get('Counter')['Count']))
    )

testlist = (SimpleListAdapter(
    data=database,
    cls=ListItemButton
))
```

I'm trying to create a contacts list using python 2.7, kivy and JsonStore. My GUI creates a popup with text inputs, which are filled in, and once the save button is pressed, the function is triggered.

This function creates a file, and inside that file, creates a list, with the list name being the contacts name, then all of their other information such as discord etc becomes part of that list.

What I want to do, is create a scrollable GUI to see all of the saved contacts in my list, to do this I was attempting to create another list using JsonStore but ran into a mountain of issues. Please help!

I need a way to call the lists so I can create a GUI using something like:

```
NameList = JsonStore('friendslist/db.json')
NameList.put('namelist', NameIn.text)
```

Comment: So you mean you want to be able to run functions with a string?

Comment: Sorry no, I wan't to make a list of the list names inside the offline.json file

Answer (score 0):

I have stripped down your question a lot, this will save and print the list of contacts.

I also like to use the `json` library.

```
import json

# List of contacts,
contacts = [("Jason", ["zomboid12321", "json@example.org"]),
            ("Ruby", ["tigerboy15", "rubylang@example.com"]),]

# Load an empty JASON file with only a list of contacts,
# Note: you could also use the `open` statement to load from
#       - an already saved JSON.
j = json.loads("""
{
    "contacts": []
}
""")

# Write contacts into JSON file,
with open('offline.json', 'w') as f:
    for contact in contacts:
        j["contacts"].append({contact[0]:contact[1]})
    f.write(json.dumps(j))

# Read contacts from file,
for contact in j['contacts']:
    name, info = list(contact.items())[0]
    print(name, info)
```

It will save the `contacts` into a `offline.json` file, then it will read the `json` into a list, it should do everything you asked :)

Also additionally, you could open the `json` instead of having the `{ "contacts": [] }` string, and then remove writing. This way, you can open a previously saved `json`.

Comment: I'm still quite confused. Sorry!

I'm trying to use the kivy JsonStore, and I'm using the function put to grab inputs from kivy text inputs into a Json.

I then need to create a list of the keys, so I can draw a GUI using the key names, and when clicked, call individual items out of the list to manipulate them in the GUI, doing things such as change font size or move in the layout.

I'm just so confused that I worded my question badly D:

Comment: I have my GUI working, and I can save to the Json using the above code, I just dont know how I can create a list of the keys

Comment: So what do you mean by `keys`? Dictionary keys? So from what I understand, you want to save a list of `keys` that you can retrieve? If it is required that you must use `JsonStore` to do `json` reading and writing, I don't know if I can help :( P.S. Also keep in mind that the `json` library is standard, and also that the code above produces a list :)